# How to read contents of file which is open in another application Qt

Tags: qt, qfile

I'm trying to read the contents of files in a folder,
but when any file form the folder is open in another application,
I am not able to read the contents of that file

How can I achieve this, reading contents of file using QFile which is open in another application

Comment: Did you open it in writing or reading mode?

Comment: What platform are you on? On windows, you cannot open a file that has already been opened with write permission.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have opened it with read only mode

Comment: @ekhumoro I'm on windows, but is there any way I can perform the task?

Comment: @KVinay. I don't think it can be done with `QFile`. You'll probably need to use [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) with the appropriate [share mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363874(v=vs.85).aspx). But note that, even then, it still may fail due to [this issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316609/prb-error-sharing-violation-error-message-when-the-createfile-function).